# Good installer that can download prerequisites on demand

Tags: .net, installation, window, windows-installer

I know, there are a lot of questions here about Installers, but all of them are old. What I need is an install maker, that can download .net framework 4.5 on demand(if user does not have it, install it) and then install my application. And it must be only one file. 
I've tried to use WiX, but it looks too complicate for me and I could not find any examples on how to make a simple installer with it. Also Ive tried to use InstallShield limited, that comes with visual studio, but it seems to be unable to download prerequisites from the web(or maybe I am missing something).

If you could help me to find a solution of my problem I'd be very gracefull. Of course, the best solution would be to make somehow InstallShield limited download nesessary data from the web.

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't mind buying a commercial one, InstallAware can do all you required.

Comment: You're either going to have to invest 6 months in learning WiX/MSI (yes, it is complicated), or spend some money on a commercial product. Installshield, Install Aware, Advanced Installer, MSI Factory are all options at different price points.

Comment: @saschabeaumont - WiX does not support bootstrapper type applications. it can do a condition check, but not actually install it if it is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As VRK said you will need the bootstrapper file, [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html) is another good setup authoring tool that does exactly what you need. However, you will need a licensed version as this feature is not available in the free edition. You can still test it during the 30 days trial period, all features are available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for .NET 4.5, as only the RC build is available, but [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

MSI Installer does have an option to install pre-requisites. but you have to run bootstrapper (setup.exe) from the setup output files.

setup.exe will detect if there is any pre-requisite needs to be installed and it will install. then continue installing your program by calling msi file.